# Subtract total expenses for each month

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following query:

```
select 
year(date) year_date,
sum(case when month(date) = 1 then  price end) January,
sum(case when month(date) = 2 then  price end) February,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) March,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) May,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) April,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) June,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) July,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) August,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) September,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) October,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) November,
sum(case when month(date) = 3 then  price end) December,
from orders
group by year(date)
order by year_date
```

I have another query to get a monthly sum of expenses:

```
SELECT SUM(expense) AS expenses_total FROM expenses
```

Any way to add this to the first query so as the end result of each month is minus the expenses?

Comment: As you have 2 table s1 with prces and the second with expanse per month join both on year and subtract january(proces) -january(expanses)

Comment: @nbk Thanks for the comment pointing me in the right direction. People love to just downvote.

Comment: please see for the next time  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just join those 2 tables?

```
select 
year(dt) year_date,
sum(case when month(dt) = 1 then  price end) - e.exp January,
sum(case when month(dt) = 2 then  price end) - e.exp February,
sum(case when month(dt) = 3 then  price end) - e.exp March,
sum(case when month(dt) = 4 then  price end) - e.exp May,
sum(case when month(dt) = 5 then  price end) - e.exp April,
sum(case when month(dt) = 6 then  price end) - e.exp June,
sum(case when month(dt) = 7 then  price end) - e.exp July,
sum(case when month(dt) = 8 then  price end) - e.exp August,
sum(case when month(dt) = 9 then  price end) - e.exp September,
sum(case when month(dt) = 10 then  price end) - e.exp October,
sum(case when month(dt) = 11 then  price end) - e.exp November,
sum(case when month(dt) = 12 then  price end) - e.exp December,
e.exp
from orders o
JOIN (select SUM(expense) AS exp from expenses) e ON 1=1
group by year(dt), exp
order by year_date
```

value of orders table
[image]

result
[image]

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c490abbdc7a70d708516a25ff0d055c8)

Comment: actually, Im one of the downvoters on your post.. it is actually a simple join, yet you didnt try it :(

Comment: I didn't try it because I never use them. I'm just starting out and learning as I go. I've read about them but I'm still not entirely on point as to where they should be used or not (situationally wise). Hence the question here. A simple thing like the comment left on the main post would have done it - no need for downvotes just because hasty to assume something. Nevertheless, I do appreciate your complete answer and it will prove helpful in helping me understand joins better, by way of example and actual usage plus whatever else learning I'll do on my own. So, thank you! :)

Comment: my bad on assuming things. but to me, your post is more like 'a teacher gave a homework to a student, the student doesnt try and directly ask in a forum for easy answer'. sorry if my downvote offend you. not trying to discourage you in learning.

Comment: That just means you're too used to people like that/or making such assumptions. I simply haven't used joins almost at all. Thanks again :D